# How to modify timeout of socket in VC++?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, winsock

My Problem description given below.

**Examples:**

I have 10 Function calls.

Increase timeout when one by one function call.

If is it possible?

If Possible then please suggest me, how can i do this?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Are you looking for [`setsockopt()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740476.aspx), by any chance? In particular, see `SO_RCVTIMEO` and `SO_SNDTIMEO` options. Since you mention MFC, see also `CAsyncSocket::SetSockOpt` (it's a wrapper around `setsockopt`)